# How do I change the content type used by a view?

Tags: views

I bought a drupal theme which has several views on the content type 'portfolio'.
Is there a way to change the content type used by those views?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! There are many settings of a view that involve a content type; we cannot list all those settings. Also, you are asking more than a question; it is better to limit to a question per... question.

Comment: Edit the view, under Filter, you should see type = 'portfolio'. Should be as simple as editing the "type" and adding/removing the types that you want.

Comment: @NoSssweat you saved my lot of time. Why not adding this as answer. I will try to reopen the qst.